# Run system process

Tags: c++, process, system

are there any crossplatform tools for C++ which will help me to run child systme processes (all I need is just running and redirecting stdout into parent). I'm using boost, and I found there boost::process, but it's unofficial. Are there any analogues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/index.html#process.download) isn't official yet in the sense it hasn't been accepted into Boost.  However, if it works for you why not use it?

Comment: Look at my comment for the second answer.

Comment: @Ockonal what does install by hands mean?

Comment: I guess he means there's no ready-to-install package for Boost.Process on his system.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to run a process and get its output, how about `popen(3)`?  It's widely used, very "official," and sounds like it does what you're looking for, without using Boost.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work? If so, why does it bother you whether it's "official" or not? Presumably, the license is the same as boost's, and you have the source code available, so you can fix potential bugs. Where's the problem?

Comment: I don't have that library in my boost version (1.43). As I understand, it should be installed by hands.

Comment: So, again, where is the problem?